# Xamarin WebView - Call C# Method

Tags: xamarin, webview

Is there a way in Xamarin's WebView that allows me to attach javascript events to my html elements and call C# method.

I could easily do this in Android by using JavaScriptInterface

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" poster='poster.gif'
       onclick="window.JSInterface.startVideo('file:///sdcard/test.3gp');"
```

How would I manage to this in Xamarin

Comment: `WebView` is not Xamarin's, it's Android's. You can use `WebView.AddJavascriptInterface` in the same way.

Comment: Have your tried Googling "xamarin android webview javascript" and clicking the very first [result](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/webview/call_csharp_from_javascript/)...?

If so, what specific problem did you run into with it?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Interestingly, I did not follow that manual, and even though I target API 14, I did not implement `IRunnable` and only used `[Export]`. It all works very well.

Comment: Good to hear, so your problem is solved it sounds like?

Comment: @Gserg : What are the equivalents in Windows and iOS for WebView and calling native methods ?

Comment: On Windows you use [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`ObjectForScripting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx). On iOS, I have no idea.