# Call c# function from javascript in Xamarin.Forms Webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to make call of some c# code when user tap on a button in html. I followed below example and also tried it and it is working for my purpose if i use it as it is.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

It uses index.html from assets, instead i want to use some URL where my html page is. But unfortunately when i change url, it stops invoking c# code.

Please let me know if there are any changes needed to get it working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin WebView - Call C# Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930626/xamarin-webview-call-c-sharp-method)

Comment: @MihailDuchev, i have same implementation, but as i said it is not working when i change URL to some hosted webpage like mydomain.com/myfile.html.

Comment: There is no reason why this won't work. I have also tried the same implementation in the past and everything was working. How are you invoking the C# method from your js? Show us some code that you have tried - have are you creating the `JavasriptInterface`?

Comment: i downloaded example hybridwebview and copy paste index.html on my domain. you can find that on above given link

Comment: Please post your demo and testing url, we cannot reproduce your issue with above demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some firewall settings blocking communication from my iOS simulator, got it fix after adding certificate.

Example demo is working fine now

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please accept your answer, it will help other who have similar issue.